# Disqus wordpress plugin doesn't connect to API

Tags: api, wordpress, disqus

I'm working with Wordpress 3.5.1, and trying to use the Disqus Plugin. It works just fine on my localhost, but not on the server.

The login screen pops up, but as soon as I enter my login information, it says:

> Unable to connect to the Disqus API servers

I've already tried to mess with some of the plugin code as shown here: [_dsq_fsockopen_urlopen() Workaround](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-connect-to-the-disqus-api-servers), but it did nothing, same error. Any ideas? I can contact the server administrator, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This error almost always has to do with a port being blocked by the server. Try contacting them to make sure that they can connect to 'disqus.com' and 'disqus.net' through port 80.

Comment: cant open disqus.net